# What does upgrading an airport actually do?

Tags: pocket-planes

In Pocket Planes on iOS, you have the option of upgrading your airports, but what advantage does that give you, and is there a finite number of times you can upgrade?

It's quite an expensive option, so don't want to waste my coins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds more jobs and layovers. This way an airport is more profitable.

I think you can upgrade three times, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Does that mean that it also increases the population count you see on the world map?

Comment: Nope. The Class of an airport is unchangeable, and it is bound by the population. So no way to change the class of an airport, or the population of the cities.

Comment: There are three levels (1/2/3) so you can upgrade twice.

In terms of layovers, a city of size 10 million will have 20 layover spots with no upgrade, 40 layovers upgraded once (to level 2) and 60 layover spots with the second upgrade to level 3.  Smaller airports start out with 5 or 10 layover spots and I think those also double and triple layover spots as well.

Comment: Yes, you can upgrade twice. The first upgrade doubles the number of layover slots, and the second upgrade increases by 1.5x again. (So level 3 = 1.5 * level 2, and level 2 = 2 * level 1.)